# UIPickerView crashes app when scrolling past beginning or end of list

Tags: iphone, view, crash, controller, picker

I'm new to iOS dev, so this is probably easy to fix. I have a custom view controller in which I'm adopting the protocols to control a UIPickerView in a nib. Everything works fine unless, in the iPad simulator, I scroll the picker beyond the first item in the list or the last item in the list and release. It kicks the following error:

Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

on this line of my main.m class:

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Relevant code follows:

ViewController.h

```
@interface BirdColorViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
IBOutlet UIPickerView *birdColorPicker;
NSArray *birdColors;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *birdColorPicker;
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)dealloc
{
[birdColorPicker release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    birdColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Yellow",@"Red",nil];

    birdColorPicker.delegate = self;
    birdColorPicker.dataSource = self;
}

...

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource methods

//(UIPickerView *)thePickerView

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return [birdColors count];
}

 #pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate methods

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return [birdColors objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    // Set value in prefs/model
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: 
`birdColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Yellow",@"Red",nil];`
instead of `birdColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Yellow",@"Red",nil];`

Comment: That fixed it. Can you educate me as to why that made the difference? I know a little bit about memory management, but it seems like this would increase the retain count. If I'm using (nonatomic,retain) and I'm alloc-init'ing here, is one release on the dealloc enough? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The @property(nonatomic, retain) shouldn't be necessary if you do it this way and in your dealloc a single `[birdColors dealloc]` should be good enough.  I prefer to do all of the management myself rather than dealing with retaining autoreleased objects and stuff.  It looks like the array was getting released prematurely in the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

Make birdColors a property also (nonatomic, retain) like you do with the pickerView.
Your array is not being retained, so you're accessing zombie memory.
Set  NSZombieEnabled=YES in the properties/General panel of your Executable.  That will tell you exactly what is being accessed.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in, Mike. I set the array to nonatomic & retain and released it like I'm doing with the view, but that didn't fix it. Still crashes when scrolling beyond beginning or end of picker list and releasing. (I didn't see where to set NSZombieEnabled as you advised.)

Comment: re: zombie - sorry - Arguements tab - bottom half, tap "+", Name is NSZombieEnabled, Value is YES, check the box.  You will see what variable is being incorrectly addressed.  Also, in your titleForRow: add this above the 'return' statement:  NSLog(@" row is %d",row);

Comment: OK, so when the view with the picker launches, it initially says: 2011-03-30 14:15:44.114 BirdApp[1435:207]  row is 2
2011-03-30 14:15:44.115 BirdApp[1435:207]  row is 1
2011-03-30 14:15:44.116 BirdApp[1435:207]  row is 0`code`, but when I scroll past the beginning and release, for example, I get 2011-03-30 14:16:01.399 BirdApp[1435:207]  row is 2
2011-03-30 14:16:01.400 BirdApp[1435:207] *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x603d080. When I select any of the rows with an actual value, I don't see anything in the output panel.

Comment: Weird...I guess something about scrolling beyond the list items in the picker is causing pickerView: titleForRow: forComponent: to run again, trying to repopulate the list?

Comment: [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x603d080   <<<--- this means your array is gone.  Can you post the code where you define your property and your dealloc?

Comment: ViewController.h `@interface BirdColorViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *birdColorPicker;
    NSArray *birdColors;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *birdColorPicker;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *birdColors;

@end`

Comment: From ViewController.m `@synthesize birdColorPicker;
@synthesize birdColors; - (void)dealloc
{
    [birdColorPicker release];
    [birdColors release];
    [super dealloc];
} - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    birdColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Yellow",@"Red",nil];
    
    birdColorPicker.delegate = self;
    birdColorPicker.dataSource = self;
}`

Comment: Thanks for hanging in there with me, Mike. I know a little bit more about how to debug now.

Comment: Try "self.birdColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects ..."